# How to log messages passing through ejabberd

Tags: logging, message, ejabberd

I would like to log when a stanza (message and presence only) was received by the ejabberd server,a nd when it was sent to the other party (or broardcast).

Whats important for me is to log the stanza and the times they are sent & received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem. I mostly want to log group chats and occasional p2p chats, preferably in mysql.
I found a module that does mysql logging, but it needs patching and recompiling, and I dont know if it will be maintained in the future:
http://www.dp.uz.gov.ua/o.palij/mod_logdb/

There are some other mods too (like mod_muc_log). Try searching ejabberd.im

If ejabberd will be programatically accessed (like in my case), the other option would be automatically including a logging bot in every conversation.

I think im gonna start with the 1st solution, though.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for both of you.
http://www.ejabberd.im/install-bandersnatch

Comment: This plugin has broken links. See the comments section on thepage. None of the alternative links work either.

Answer (score 0):

this might be what you are looking for

**http://www.ejabberd.im/mod_logxml**

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are interested to log stanzas and presence occurrence for the group chat, go with mod_muc_log module  https://www.ejabberd.im/mod_muc_log